# Webscraping Roblox

Tags: python, selenium, roblox

My problem is that I am webscraping my sales on roblox with selenium, because requests returns the false value everytime so I made selenium write my json response to a text file.

And now I want to only get the sales value from it, how do I do this?

Here is my python function, and my response.txt

```
def submitData(self):
        self.title.setText("Roblox Sales Checker")
        try:
            ID = self.ID_INPUT.text()
            url = f'https://api.roblox.com/Marketplace/ProductInfo?assetId={ID}'

            driver.get(url)
            driver.add_cookie("My Auth Cookie,but not for you :)")
            driver.refresh()

            search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > pre").text

            f = open('apiResponse.txt', 'w')
            f.write(search)
            f.close()

            f = open('apiResponse.txt', 'r+')
            apiResponseText = f.readlines()

            print(apiResponseText)
```

```
{"TargetId":6970745869,"ProductType":"User Product","AssetId":6970745869,"ProductId":1183920723,"Name":"beautifulSky","Description":"","AssetTypeId":10,"Creator":{"Id":2657343484,"Name":"Bestgamedev1209","CreatorType":"User","CreatorTargetId":2657343484},"IconImageAssetId":0,"Created":"2021-06-18T15:12:36.253Z","Updated":"2021-06-18T15:12:36.297Z","PriceInRobux":null,"PriceInTickets":null,"Sales":20624,"IsNew":false,"IsForSale":false,"IsPublicDomain":true,"IsLimited":false,"IsLimitedUnique":false,"Remaining":null,"MinimumMembershipLevel":0,"ContentRatingTypeId":0}
```

Comment: when I paste your json into the json parser at http://json.parser.online.fr/, it fails. That makes it harder to parse.

Comment: Changed the json now it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `import json`, Sales will be given as:

```
json.loads(apiResponseText)["Sales"]
```

Here is a small example:

```
import json
apiResponseText='{"TargetId":6970745869,"ProductType":"User Product","AssetId":6970745869,"ProductId":1183920723,"Name":"beautifulSky","Description":"","AssetTypeId":10,"Creator":{"Id":2657343484,"Name":"Bestgamedev1209","CreatorType":"User","CreatorTargetId":2657343484},"IconImageAssetId":0,"Created":"2021-06-18T15:12:36.253Z","Updated":"2021-06-18T15:12:36.297Z","PriceInRobux":null,"PriceInTickets":null,"Sales":20624,"IsNew":false,"IsForSale":false,"IsPublicDomain":true,"IsLimited":false,"IsLimitedUnique":false,"Remaining":null,"MinimumMembershipLevel":0,"ContentRatingTypeId":0}'
y=json.loads(apiResponseText)["Sales"]
print(y)
```

and the output is:

```
20624
```

Comment: it is not working when I am printing it out

Comment: now its working, I had to change apiResponse = f.readlines() to apiResponse = f.read()

Comment: so one last thing, when I want to show the value in my gui, it is not working :/ I am using PyQt5 and this is my line to show it: ```self.output_label.setText("Sales: " + sales)```

Comment: "Sales: " + str(sales) you cannot concat string and int